# Alsa vdownmix config - how to use with different devices?

Tags: audio, alsa, dsp

I am trying to configure ALSA to downmix 5.1 surround audio to 2.0 stereo. There is an ALSA output plugin `vdownmix` that seems to do exactly this, but I can only seem to use it with my onboard audio instead of my USB soundcard, despite the USB soundcard being set to default. The config in question is `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf.d/60-vdownmix.conf` (from Debian bullseye `libasound2-plugins`):

```
    @args [ SLAVE CHANNELS DELAY ]
    @args.SLAVE {
        type string
        default "plug:hw"
    }
    @args.CHANNELS {
        type integer
        default 6
    }
    @args.DELAY {
        type integer
        default 0
    }
    type vdownmix
    slave.pcm $SLAVE
    hint {
        show {
            @func refer
            name defaults.namehint.basic
        }
                description "Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization"
    }
}
```

The issue seems to be the line `default "plug:hw"`, this seems to only let me use my onboard sound instead of USB. What is the proper syntax to tell that to use my USB sound card, or better yet, is it possible for me to modify that to let me use an arbitrary slave device?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is to change that line to default `"plug:hw:1"`, to manually tell it a card. Though using vdownmnix limits you to 16 bit audio.